# Authenticate to google cloud as a service account on browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to migrate my google cloud app from Nodejs to native JavaScript, such that it can be run in the browser. However, I can't seem to find any examples of how to authenticate as a service account in the browser. Authenticating in Nodejs looked like this:

```
const textToSpeech = require('@google-cloud/text-to-speech');
const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');

const projectId = 'project'
const keyFilename = 'key.json'

const storage = new Storage({projectId, keyFilename});

const client = new textToSpeech.TextToSpeechClient({projectId, keyFilename});
```

In all of the searching I've done, I've only ever found solutions that use API keys and Client IDs. Additionally, all of these solutions prompt for a user to login, which is not what I want. I'd like to do exactly what the Nodejs code is doing, but in native browser JavaScript.

Comment: Have you already checked [gcp docs](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts#:~:text=cannot%20log%20in%20via%20browsers) that says that a `service account` cannot log in via browsers?

Comment: No I didn't see that @Darwin In that case, how can I authenticate to google cloud via browser without using a log in prompt? My app doesn't involve an actual user to activate it, so a prompt won't work.

Comment: To connect to a Google Cloud Service (ex: Cloud Storage) you need to set up authentication. Based on my understanding on your question, you can use a Service account, It does not require prompt login in the browser. you may try to check this [sample link](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-nodejs)  on how to connect with Cloud Storage or [this link](https://github.com/googlearchive/storage-getting-started-javascript/blob/master/index.html) using native javascript

Comment: @Darwin When using the code in the GitHub link, I get the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setApiKey')". Is this snippet outdated? How can I resolve this? Here is the function:

 `function handleClientLoad() {
                gapi.client.setApiKey(CREDS["credentials"][0]["gcloud"]["GC_API_KEY"]);
                window.setTimeout(checkAuth, 1);
              }`

Comment: Yes, the repo is an old project, I suggest to create an issue directly on the github repository. Lastly, I found another repo that uses [native javascript](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/storage-metabucket-javascript) for gcp but it's also no longer maintained.

Answer (score 0):

[google-auth-library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-auth-library) allows loading creds from hardcoded text:

```js
const {auth} = require('google-auth-library');
const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');

const authClient = auth.fromJSON({
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "your-project-id",
  "private_key_id": "your-private-key-id",
  "private_key": "your-private-key",
  "client_email": "your-client-email",
  "client_id": "your-client-id",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "your-cert-url"
});
const storage = new Storage({authClient});
```

However you should be careful. Embedded credentials can be extracted, and then anyone can make any call as this service account. Theoretically you can be safe with carefully restricted access, but this is easy to make a mistake.

For GCS you are likely better off with [Signed URLs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls) or some other solution that keeps credentials on the server.

Comment: But, that is a Nodejs library. I need an authentication solution for native JavaScript. @David